# iPad Air 2 not turning on

Tags: ipad

My iPad Air 2 was working fine until yesterday. Then I turned it off for a while, and when I returned, I plugged my headphones in and typed in my passcode to go to the homescreen. However, the iPad froze before the homescreen loaded, so I switched off the iPad to restart it. Since I turned it off, I have been unable to get it to turn on again (the screen is black). I plugged it in and it made the "I'm charging" ding but the screen didn't turn on to show my lock screen. I clicked the on sleep/wake button and home button a few times but nothing happened. It was fully charged before this happened. What can I do to turn on my iPad again?

Answer (score 1):

My own iPad Air shut off by itself last month (with the charge reading at 80%) and wouldn't turn on, even when I plugged it in. After 30 minutes of it being plugged in, the screen was still black. However, I left the iPad charging for about an hour and finally the screen came back on.

Try charging it for an hour, and plugging it into iTunes to see if you get a response from it.